# maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis with concurrent transactions

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the lock acquisition behavior on MongoDB transactions. I have a scenario where two concurrent transactions try to modify the same document. Since one transaction will get the write lock on the document first, the second transaction will run into a write conflict and fail.

I stumbled upon the `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` setting as documented here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis and it states:

> The maximum amount of time in milliseconds that multi-document transactions should wait to acquire locks required by the operations in the transaction.

However, changing this value does not seem to have an impact on the observed behavior with a write conflict. Transaction 2 does not seem to wait for the lock to be released again but immediately runs into a write conflict when another transaction holds the lock (other than concurrent writes outside a transaction which will block and wait for the lock).

Do I understand correctly that the configured time in `maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis` does not include the act of actually receiving the write lock on the document or is there something wrong with my tests?

Comment: it doesn't impact writeConflicts since the locks are only taken on collection or DB level (like if someone is running an admin command to change some collection attribute, that requires an exclusive lock.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, if locks are taken on collection or DB level, why Transaction 2 does not try to take the same lock and wait? 
If maxTransactionLockRequestTimeoutMillis does not solve problem Sabacc tries to solve, what's it for?
Somewhat unrelated point is that taking lock at such high scope would be very inefficient as it reduces concurrency, most DBs try to lock at record/document level. I doubt mongodb would take that approach.

Comment: Mainly to avoid potential deadlock scenarios.